# detecting all intersecting points between lines

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am using bellow query to get all the intersecting points from my line_string table.

```
select a.line_id,(st_dump(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom from 
roads a, roads b where st_touches(a.geom, b.geom);
```

Though it detects most of the intersecting points, its not detecting all the intersecting points.
[image]

In the above image blue dots are all detected points, where as red boxes are missed in detection.

There will be 2 possibilities.

One is marked in green, where roads are not intersecting (fly-over/under pass roads). Where geometry is not touching. OR two lines are not snapped/connected correctly.

But in the above image I cross checked many non detected lines, but they are perfectly snapped/connected.

I can use `ST_Intersects` in place of `ST_Touches` But the problem is,(If i am not wrong) it matches geometry spatially which leads to detecting intersecting points in flyover / underpass roads also.

Can anyone help me in understanding why its not detecting all intersecting points and how to correct it?

I also need to detect start or end point which is not intersected with other lines as intersecting point.

Answer (score 3):

[ST_Touches](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html) explain that:

> Returns TRUE if the geometries have at least one point in common,
>   **but their interiors do not intersect**.

So you can detect points start and end point of lines but not interior vertex by using ST_Touches.

You should use [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) for your aim :

> Returns TRUE if the Geometries/Geography "spatially
>   intersect in 2D" - (**share any portion of space**) and FALSE if they
>   don't (they are Disjoint). For geography -- tolerance is 0.00001
>   meters (so any points that close are considered to intersect)

But Return of ST_Intersection will be LineString.

So your query should be like :

```
select a.line_id,st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) from 
roads a, roads b where st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
and geometrytype(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))='POINT'
and a.geom&&b.geom -- to accelerate query
and a.line_id!=b.line_id;
```

Comment: So how should I modify my query?

Comment: i edited answer.

Comment: Would ST_Node be of any help to you? I'll link to [my blog post](https://www.zimmi.cz/posts/2015/postgis-count-line-self-intersections/) dealing with its use. You might find it necessary to `ST_Union` the lines, the `ST_Node` them and `ST_Dump` them again.

Comment: @BarışSerkanAKIN Still it detects points where flyover/underpass is there (Two lines looks like connected but they are not actually connected. A sub road passes under main road or something like).

Comment: Hi @Dharshan. Sql Query detects spatial intersections, doesn't know your model. You can add some condition after `where` like `a.road_type<>'Subroad'`. You can also select multiple query for each   condition , then union all.

Comment: I will try on both ST_Node and other methods.